# Using JQuery/JS to store the id of a <td> on click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a bunch of data. Each `<td>` contains `class="person"` and `id=0,1,2,3, etc.` based on `$i` (I'm using a loop to build my table from an array).

I'd like it so that whenever a person (`<td>`) is clicked, that cell gets highlighted with some css.

So far I think I can use this:

> $('.person').click(function(){
>
> ```
> $id = some function to which attr('id') was selected???;
> $('id').addClass("highlights");
> ```
>
> });

Does anyone know how I can fetch the ID of the cell being clicked? Any help or approaches appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.id` refers to the `id` of the `td` inside the method.

```
$('.person').click(function(){

    var id = this.id;
    $('#' +id).addClass("highlights");

});
```

But if you want to just change something on the element, then you do not really need the `id`. That is because the `this` keyword refers to the actual clicked element.

So you can directly do

```
$('.person').click(function
    $(this).addClass("highlights");
});
```

---

Beware, though, that the id of an element [cannot be numeric](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) (*as far as **valid html** is concerned..*)

And i quote

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Excellent, thank you, that was easier than expected! I thought that using $(this).addClass would have applied that class to all "person" classes, but click() returns the ID? How could I know that (it didn't mention that in the API) for next time?

Comment: @user339946, looking at the [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) documentation which is the core of the event binding system in jquery, you will find the **Within the handler, the keyword *`this`* refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound.**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.person').click(function(){

$(this).addClass("highlights");

});
```

Sometimes, you can forget about id in jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").click(function(e){

alert($(this).attr('id'));
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xELyx/1/

also have a look at jquery id selectors http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

and

`attr` http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Seems to be the line you want :)

Comment: Please.. don't! don't use jQuery where it's not needed and simple JavaScript can be used. Look at @Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer if you don't understand what I'm talking about.